# Can I use my Android phone as a second monitor?

Tags: samsung, secondary-display

About ten years ago I started using dual monitors. It was amazing. But I switched to using a laptop exclusively and do not have a second monitor. It occurred to me that I have a second screen right next to me (my phone) that I'm not using.

Is it possible to use it as a second monitor? I can imagine using it to show a training video while I follow along on my laptop screen.

I have a Mac OSX 10.11 and a Samsung Galaxy 6. I have an older iPhone 4S as well.

Comment: Do you imagine or prioritize usage other than to show videos on the phone?

Comment: I've read an article on that quite a while ago, but don't remember the source. A quick check on "second screen" brought up [Air Duet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=superle.airduetscreen), which seems to do exactly what you're asking for. Maybe take a look? Btw: The OS on your PC/Laptop plays a role here (the app mentioned e.g. needs a Windows counterpart), so you might wish to [edit] your question and include that.

Comment: A phone is rather small.  Perhaps somewhat useful as a second monitor, but not so useful.  A nice-sized tablet (diagonally 10 inches or more) would make a better second monitor.

Comment: NoMachine and a 2nd X(org) session (I am on linux btw and that is what I would do)